# Can I check what the allocation unit size is on my drives via a query?

Tags: sql-server

Assuming that I do not have access to windows server, can I run a script from SSMS that would allow me to check whether allocation unit size is formatted with 64K?

Comment: Why do you think SSMS is the right tool for these kinds of things? What are you going to do with the output in SSMS?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is one way:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo "C:"';
```

Line 9 shows, e.g.:

```
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
```

There are obviously more powerful ways to do this using, e.g. PowerShell, but as I suggested in my comment, it's hard to understand exactly what you're going to do with the output in SSMS, and what kind of effort you're willing to go to in order to use these methods from within SSMS... I'd say it's much better to get these values externally (which gives you so many more options), then update a table you can query from within SSMS.

Comment: +1 - It would almost make more sense just to call a script from xpcmdshell that populates a table through powershell or something.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that fsutil [requires administrator privileges](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753059(v=ws.10)), which hopefully the xp_cmdshell proxy doesn't have. I certainly agree with the general conclusion that this is better done externally than from within SQL Server, although if the OP has no OS-level access then presumably it's a hosted database server of some kind.

Comment: @Pondlife and if it's a hosted server, what are you going to do with this information anyway?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Exactly, I was also wondering about that. I assume if it's hosted by an external provider then the information has no practical value, and if it's hosted internally then the OP should just request the details from the sysadmin team.